# Is A Company Abusing The Tax Code When It Does This, And How Does The IRS Prevent It?

Tags: taxes, charity, charitable-contributions

When answering, please cite specifics. Which section of the tax code deals with this abuse? What cases have been prosecuted?

This SO answer describes an abusive tax scheme involving non-cash assets being donated at inflated values. How does the tax code prevent this?

> If you have a software company, that can produce a box of software for $5, but the box sells for $100. (You have to make a profit and cover development costs)
>
> But then you give these boxes to charity, that is a cost of $5 each and a tax rebate of $100 x 40% = $40. A profit of $35 per donation of $5.

Which was critiqued as follows:

> Critique: This sounds like an intentional abuse of the system. The IRS often investigates schemes where non-cash assets are donated for an inflated "full value". – Chris W. Rea Apr 7 '12 at 16:24

For clarity: The question is: **How does the tax code prevent this?** Sub questions to guide your answer are: Which section of the tax code deals with this abuse? What cases have been prosecuted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: I see four questions

Comment: With the recent edit, two of those questions are asked twice.

Comment: @NathanL: For clarity, I repeated the question (and sub-questions) at the end because apparently some people are missing them when they are at the top.

Comment: Also voting to close.  It isn't a question relevant to "personal" finance.

Comment: @DanielAnderson: It's a tax question for people who happen to own a small business. Therefore, I believe, that qualifies as a question about personal finance. Does it not?

Comment: I'll conditionally withdraw my close vote, dependent on how others respond to it.

Comment: I think this is not about personal finance either; you're asking a business question. Small business questions are on topic only in certain areas; small business accounting I don't think is, and I don't see how this is specifically a small business question.  This further is (explicitly) a legal question (As you're specifically asking for the section of the law), and sounds like it might be more of a [law.se] question?

Comment: You're asking a mostly rhetorical question about how tax authorities police a very narrow aspect of corporate tax law.  I don't know how you expect anyone to answer, or provide you with your conspicuously requested specifics...  The IRS polices it the same way it polices every other aspect of tax law, by seeking records in the event of an audit.

Answer (score 5):

[A rather good IRS paper](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/eotopice94.pdf) on the topic states that a donation of a business' in-kind inventory would be

> Under IRC 170(e)(1), however, the fair market value must be
>   reduced by the amount of gain that would not be long-term capital gain if the
>   property had been sold by the donor at the property's fair market value (determined
>   at the time of the contribution). Under this rule, deductions for donated inventory
>   are limited to the property's basis (generally its cost), where the fair market value
>   exceeds the basis.

There are references to IRC regulations in a narrative context you may find helpful:

> - a deduction under IRC 170(e)(3)
> - see Reg. 1.170A-4A(c)(2)-(3), regarding adjustments
> - General guidance on determining fair market value of donated property is
>     found in the regulations. Reg. 1.170A-1(c)(2) and (3) provide ...

This paper goes on for 16 pages describing detailed exceptions and the political reasons for the exceptions (most of which are concerned with encouraging the donation of prepared food from restaurants/caterers to hunger charities by guaranteeing a value for something that would otherwise be trashed valueless); and a worked out example of fur coats that had a cost of goods of $200 and a market value of $1000.